# Find a line in file and prepend character if not already present

Tags: powershell

I am having a file with multiple entries like below

```
Application Host Helper Service,OS,WARNING
Base Filtering Engine,OS,WARNING
Background Tasks Infrastructure Service,OS,WARNING
Connected Devices Platform Service,OS,WARNING
#Remote Registry,OS,WARNING
#Background Intelligent Transfer Service,OS,WARNING
VMware Tools,OS,WARNING
#Windows Modules Installer,OS,WARNING
```

I need to find below 4 entries in the file and prepend **#** to these entries if `#` is already not present.

```
#Connected Devices Platform Service,OS,WARNING
#Remote Registry,OS,WARNING
#Windows Modules Installer,OS,WARNING
#Background Intelligent Transfer Service,OS,WARNING
```

so, as you can see, in the file apart from the first entry (Connected Devices Platform Service,OS,WARNING), all are already having **#**. so the script should put **#** in front of the entry and leave rest as it is.

I was trying the below code, but it is instead of putting **#** to the existing entry, it is creating a new entry in the file and putting **#**.

```
$svr = $env:COMPUTERNAME

$CheckbeforeRenamedFile = Test-Path -Path "\\$svr\c$\Tivoli_Configs\Monitor_Services\Services_Mon_25042023.txt"
$entries = @(
    "Connected Devices Platform Service,OS,WARNING",
    "Remote Registry,OS,WARNING",
    "Windows Modules Installer,OS,WARNING",
    "Background Intelligent Transfer Service,OS,WARNING"
    # Add more entries here if needed
)

foreach ($entry in $entries) {
    $fileContent = Get-Content "\\$svr\c$\Tivoli_Configs\Monitor_Services\Services_Mon_25042023.txt"
foreach($line in $fileContent){
    if ($line -match "^$entry") {
        if($entry -notmatch "#")
        {
        $fileContent += "#$line"
        Set-Content "\\$svr\c$\Tivoli_Configs\Monitor_Services\Services_Mon_25042023.txt" -Value $fileContent
        Write-Host "Added '#' for entry: $entry"
        }
    } 
}
}
```

Please let me know what I am doing wrong here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it is adding new rows to the file instead of replacing is due to the line

```
 $fileContent += "#$line"
```

You are taking the file content into $fileContent and then adding the fixed line on top of it.

You can instead pass the fixed text into a new empty variable and set it as the file content.

This is a working script. Each row contains an explanation.

**Notice that I introduced a few good practices in here:**

1. Using variables are always good way of making your way more readable.
2. Reading files can be an expansive process, if you can read it only once instead - better.
3. For performance and simplicity try to avoid loops within loops.

```
$svr = $env:COMPUTERNAME #Get Computer name from Environment variables
$TXTPath= "\\$svr\c$\Tivoli_Configs\Monitor_Services\Services_Mon_25042023.txt" #Set the Path to the TXT file once


if(Test-Path -Path $TXTPath) #if file exists then do the following:
{
$entries = @( #Set up an array with the lines to check if exist in the TXT File
    "Connected Devices Platform Service,OS,WARNING",
    "Remote Registry,OS,WARNING",
    "Windows Modules Installer,OS,WARNING",
    "Background Intelligent Transfer Service,OS,WARNING"
    # Add more entries here if needed
)
$fileContent = Get-Content $TXTPath #Load the TXT file content once
$NewContent='' #prepare new varible to save the new content temporarily

foreach ( $line in $fileContent ){ #Get-content is setting each new line in the TXT file as a new block in the array.
    if($entries -contains $line) #if the line checked is matching exactly one of the enetries then do the following:
    {
        $NewContent=$NewContent + "#" + $line + "`n" # set NewContent to be its current value + # + the current line + new line
    }
    else{
        $NewContent=$NewContent + $line + "`n" # if not, set NewContent to be its current value + the current line + new line
    }
}
Set-Content $TXTPath -Value $NewContent -Force #Update the TXT File with the new content with overwrite enabled.
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. worked perfectly as expected. appreciated!!!